# Rails, i need to  decode Base64 ziped pdf file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need to decode base64 ziped pdf file and write decoded data to a tempfile . And need to save it on over local file system.in rails.

Comment: Cool story, bro. But what have you tried?

Comment: Why not share your solution as an answer and then mark it as an accepted answer ?

Answer (score 1):

```
decoded_data=Base64.decode64(encoded_data)
file_name = "test.zip"
temp_file = Tempfile.new("filename-#{Time.now}")
File.open(temp_file, 'wb') {|f| f.write(decoded_data)}
send_file temp_file.path, :type => 'application/zip', :filename => file_name
```

Comment: I've changed the formatting - to be rendered as a code block. Nothing changed in the text. Code blocks always look better when properly formatted.